# Поднятие IM + SIP сервера для корпоративной сети.

Tags: xmpp, linux

Поделитесь опытом с ленивым админом. Нужно поднять IM и SIP сервер для корпоративной сети. У кого был опыт, подскажите что лучше в качестве сервера и клиента. Требование к клиенту - в одной программе возможность текстового и голосового общения. Копал в сторону Jabber сервера, ну уж очень много там всего, хотелось бы услышать реальный опыт со всеми подводными камнями, иначе зачем ещё нужны подобные форумы. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте jabber-сервер openfire. Легко ставится, конфигурится через веб-интерфейс, имеет кучу полезных плагинов. Была одна проблема, сам по себе тихонько умирал (FreeBSD 7.2), не зависимо от нагрузки, времени суток или фазы луны, лечилось скриптом проверяющим наличие процесса и в случае его отсутствия - перезапуск.